# In JavaFX, how can I start a DragEvent from an object that is NOT of instance Node

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, google-maps-api-3

Simplified Problem:

I want to implement a Drag and Drop feature in my JavaFX application. However, my drag object can not be the gesture source for DnD (Drag and Drop), because it is neither a Node nor a Scene.

Real Problem:

I use GMapsFX (basically Java version of google-maps-v3 API) in my JavaFX application to display a google map. The map contains markers, which I want to drag out of the WebView and place it somewhere else in any Drop Target from JavaFX. Remember, the Drag and Drop API of JavaFX can only be used with objects of instance Node/Scene. The markers in the google map are JavaScriptObjects and are therefore no valid gesture source for DnD.

I am trying very hard for days and I can not find any similar topic on the internet. I am starting to believe that it just does not work. Maybe someone has done it before and can help me?

Looking forward to your answers
Thank you

Comment: hmm .. how is the data exported by maps? And how do you expect to convert that format into something fx understands? Don't quite understand what you are after .. A couple of asides: please don't shout (aka: bold words) - that hinders the reading flow considerably, IMO. And what has maven to do with the problem?

Comment: @kleopatra The map works with the class JavaFXWebEngine. I think this is the point where map gets exported/imported. (I edited my post and removed maven tag and the bold words)

Comment: What I am after: I want to Drag n Drop a google Marker (which is of false instance) to any JavaFX node (textfield for example). But the Drag and Drop feature does not allow to set google markers as gesture source (the to be dragged object). --> how can I make a google marker draggable with the DnD feature of JavaFX?